# JSоn file is not read

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I do localization in my game, and I write words in different languages into a JSon file. Everything works in Unity Editor, but on android it throws an exception Cannot find file!

```
 public void LoadLocalizedText(string langName)
    {

#if UNITY_ANDROID && !UNITY_EDITOR
                string path ="jar:file://" + Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/Languages/" + langName + ".json";
#else
        string path = Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/Languages/" + langName + ".json";
#endif

        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            if (File.Exists(path))
            {
                string dataAsJson;

#if UNITY_ANDROID && !UNITY_EDITOR
          WWW reader = new WWW(path);
            UnityWebRequest unityWebRequest = new UnityWebRequest(path);
            while (!reader.isDone) { }
            dataAsJson = reader.text;
#else
                dataAsJson = File.ReadAllText(path);
#endif
                LocalizationData loadedData = JsonUtility.FromJson<LocalizationData>(dataAsJson);

                localizedText = new Dictionary<string, string>();
               
                for (int i = 0; i < loadedData.items.Length; i++)
                {
                    localizedText.Add(loadedData.items[i].key, loadedData.items[i].value);
                }

                currentLanguage = langName;
                isReady = true;

                OnLanguageChanged?.Invoke();
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Cannot find file!");
            }


        }
```

Comment: Well, that's not too surprising (that you get environment-specific results), you look in different places depending on what environment you are using (`#if UNITY_ANDROID && !UNITY_EDITOR`).  I'm not familiar with _jar files_, but I'm guessing there are some tools that let you look inside them to see if the file you are looking for is in the right place

Comment: print out the value of "path" on your "ANDROID" & "UNITY EDITOR" and compare. both are probably resolving to different values. you can set the base path in the config of both and call in code.

Comment: In general use [`Path.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine) for system paths!

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to add "jar:file//" on android for streaming assets path. Also, if you on android, you'll not pass your File.Exists(pass) checks. [Here is the working exapmple.](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1695033/loading-asset-in-android-using-streamingassets-and.html)